# Encrypted hard-drive I can't reformat in Disk Utility

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, fusion-drive

I have an external HDD I wish to reform (erase) so I can put inside my MBP and make a DIY fusion drive. I've done the fusion drive before but Apple made me remove it for a logic board replacement.

My question I have is regarding the formatting of the drive. It's possible to erase and reformat at the drive unit level and the partition level. And you can have it ExFAT at one level while Mac-OS Journaled at the other level. Wondering what the differences are and which is "better" for stable use as part of a fusion drive?

I just reformatted as journaled format and it says 660 MB is used already. Formatting? Formatted ExFat at drive level it says in Finder the patron is using 1 MB of storage.

Also how to change the name at drive level (not that you see it in Finder but it can get confusing in Disk Utility). Disk Utility only has two of the normal five tabs, RAID, Partition, and Restore are all missing for this drive.

One other thing, I had it refusing it's password when I had it as encrypted. Eventually after trying on two MBPs and restarting one with drive plugged in it accepted the correct password. Gave me the yips, why would it be doing that?!

Comment: There are too many questions here. Ask Different works best when there is one clear question to answer; with appropriate research & conclusions.

Comment: I got it all working anyhow… persistence and changing Macs eventually it accepted correct password and was able to iterate through the options.